# Pound key/Hash key/hashtag in php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, hashtag

I am working with Drupal currently and they have this thing with render arrays. They are putting pound keys in front of the configuration indexes of their render arrays which are then used by the render functions.

BUT! the problem has nothing to do with Drupal. The code I am providing in the next couple of lines is completely independent from any php application. Vanilla PHP as some would say.

```
   <?php
    $array = array(
      '#title' => 'Social media button settings',
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      array(
        '#title' => 'Facebook',
        '#type' => 'input',
      )
    );

    foreach($array as $i => $d) {
      // This line could contain ANY!!! key as long as it starts
      // with a pound key.
      if (isset($d['#title'])) {
        var_dump('Index: ' . $i);
        echo 'Data:';
        var_dump($d);
        var_dump('$d["#title"]: ' . $d['#title']);
      }
    }
```

Output is:

```
string 'Index: #title' (length=13)

Data:

string 'Social media button settings' (length=28)

string '$d["#title"]: S' (length=15)

string 'Index: #type' (length=12)

Data:

string 'fieldset' (length=8)

string '$d["#title"]: f' (length=15)

string 'Index: 0' (length=8)

Data:

array (size=2)
  '#title' => string 'Facebook' (length=8)
  '#type' => string 'input' (length=5)

string '$d["#title"]: Facebook' (length=22)
```

Expected output would be:

```
string 'Index: 0' (length=8)

Data:

array (size=2)
  '#title' => string 'Facebook' (length=8)
  '#type' => string 'input' (length=5)

string '$d["#title"]: Facebook' (length=22)
```

Am I not seeing something here?
Is this just something really nasty wrong in PHP?

Would be great to hear from you guys.

func0der

Update ------>>

I am using PHP 5.3.27 wrapped by MAMP.
And tried it here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/
Same results both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gives me the output you want. I suspect there is something
in the environment that messes it up. Or you have made a mistake in
copying it or something like that.

-edit-

Conclusion of comments below: isset is buggy in 5.3 and previous. Fixed
in 5.4. From php.net:

> Non-numeric string offsets - e.g. $a['foo'] where $a is a string - now return false on
>   isset() and true on empty(), and produce a E_WARNING if you try to use them. Offsets of
>   types double, bool and null produce a E_NOTICE. Numeric strings (e.g. $a['2']) still
>   work as before. Note that offsets like '12.3' and '5 foobar' are considered non-numeric
>   and produce a E_WARNING, but are converted to 12 and 5 respectively, for backward
>   compatibility reasons. Note: Following code returns different result. $str='abc';
>   var_dump(isset($str['x'])); // false for PHP 5.4 or later, but true for 5.3 or less

Comment: How would that even be possible, if you copied my exact same code?
I tried it here: http://writecodeonline.com/php
Same result. It is a completely different environment.

Comment: Cool. Yes, I've copied the same code. It seems to be a matter of different php versions. 5.4, 5.5 works fine, but not 5.3. Tested it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and on my machine running 5.4

Comment: It's a problem with isset I think. http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.
Thought I was stupid ^^
None of the php bugs ever crossed my work, but now: FINALLY^^

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong, your expectation simply disagrees with how PHP works.

If you want the "title" and "type" values to be treated as pairs you need to somehow group them together (not just "put them next to each other"). One way to do that would be to wrap another array around each pair, which would result in your expected output. You are already doing this for the Facebook/input pair, so removing the rest of the data gives the output you expect:

```
$array = array(
  array(
    '#title' => 'Facebook',
    '#type' => 'input',
  )
);
```

Comment: I know. You do not get the point here.
I can not let me throw data away and say it works then. My array is as is should be. It is a nested form array. Fieldset containing input fields. The outside pound key indexes are for the configuration of the fieldset. The other ones are for the configuration of the input fields. Completely valid.

Comment: I meant "You can not let me throw data aways...".

Comment: +1 for being right. Your array has two entries, then a subarray, yet @func0der you are expecting just the subarray to come out.

Comment: @func0der: I 'm not saying you should throw the data away. I 'm saying that the data being there obviously affects the result. The question is not well specified, so I can't offer more concrete suggestions (e.g. why do you expect `$i` to be 0?)

Comment: @Jon I gave my data, which is in `$array`. There is not more or less than that.
My expectation was, and I think it was clear, that if the current `$d` is an array (I did not check that specifically, I know) and in the index `#type` there is a "value", I want to output some data.
I do not expect `$i` to be 0. I only expect the sub-array to cause an output.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I have data and I have an expectation. You can not change my data to match my expectation. Data may have come from an external source. If so, I would have run a loop to bring them in a different format. Same problem.

Comment: @func0der: You said it yourself: `if(is_array($d))`. FYI, I hope you agree that before that was made clear it was impossible to properly answer your question.

Comment: @Jon No, sorry, I am not, since monocell understood me quite well.
But since we are arguing over nothing here, lets call it a day, shall we?

Comment: @func0der: We are not arguing (at least not as I see it), sure.